# Is there a way to make a div the height of something other than it's parent?

Tags: html, css

I have code something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

`.1 {height: 20px; width: 20px;}`

I am trying to make the class 2 div `100%` width and height of the body, instead of just the parent div. Is there any way to do this without changing the size of the parent div?

Comment: `.2 { height:100%; width:100% }`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the viewport-percentage units `vh` (viewport height) and `vw` (viewport width):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.b {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

This does, of course, come with the caveat that this is the percentage of the *viewport*, which isn't necessarily the same as the height/width of the viewport itself.

Also, I've changed the class-names, since selecting an element in CSS whose class-name, or `id`, starts with a number requires that number to be properly escaped. It can be done, but it's a needless complexity.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that just set `position:absolute` to child and `width:100%` `height:100%`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.one {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blueviolet;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the body of your page is the same width as the viewport, you would use the `vw` and `vh` units, which equal the width of the viewport and the height of the viewport, respectively. Beyond this, there is no way to reference the height of an unrelated class using pure CSS. You can accomplish it with JS, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var two = document.getElementsByClassName("2")[0];
    two.style.height = body.style.height;
}, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

## html

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="graph-box">
<div class="row">
<div class="GridH">
```

## Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
AdjustHeight();
});

function AdjustHeight() {
var WrapH = $("#wrap").height();
if (WrapH === $("#wrap").height()) {
var GridH = "";
GridH = (50* WrapH) / 100;
}
```

In above html code irrespective of graph Div and Row Div, the height of GridH Div is set to 50% of Wrap Div which is not parent Div....
Its Works Perfect for me

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution. You can give `position: absolute` to the child element:

```
.b {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that none of the parent elements can have `position: relative` added.

Personally I would go with @David Thomas answer as it should work in most cases.